# Gdocs api - Element "person" issue

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

When I write "@Me" in a Doc, a "person" element is created in the document structure

```
person: 
 personProperties{
  name: 'Me',
  email 'me@me'
 }
```

For example, if a call gdocs-api."get('documentID')" the element is listed in the body.content.paragraph.element.person

Is tere a way to create such element with gdocs api?

Comment: What person element? Is this in the UI? Can you explain a little more about what you mean? Where do you see this?

Comment: When I call the gdocs-api with "get('documentID')" the element is listed in the body.content.paragraph.element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an open issue in the Google IssueTracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184930301

PS: IssueTracker is kinda messy at first sight, but i've found it there.